# Sum values of a single row?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a MySQL query that returns a single row that is a series of 1s and 0s. It's for a progress bar indicator. I have the summing of it in code now, but I tried to sum the values in a query, and realized I couldn't use SUM(), because they're many columns but just one row.

Is there a way I can sum this automatically in the query? It's like this:

```
item_1 | item_2 | item_3 | item_4
-------+--------+--------+--------
     1 |      1 |      0 |      0
```

---

Edit: I forgot to mention, `item_1` and so forth are not simple field values, but each is rather an expression, such as `SELECT IF( field_1 = 1 and field_2 IS NOT NULL, 0, 1 ) AS item_1 ...`, so it looks like I have to do a nested query:

```
SELECT ( item_1 + item_2 ... ) FROM ( SELECT IF( field_1 = y and field_2 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) AS item_1 ... ) AS alias
```

Correct?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
select item_1 + item_2 + item_3 + item_4 as ItemSum
from MyTable
```

If there can be null values, you'll need to handle them like this:

```
select ifnull(item_1, 0) + ifnull(item_2, 0) + ifnull(item_3, 0) + ifnull(item_4, 0) as ItemSum
from MyTable
```

Comment: Ah! So since they are expressions, and not simple values, I could do a nested query: SELECT ( item_1 + item_2 ... ) FROM ( SELECT IF( field_1 = y and field_2 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) AS item_1 ... ) AS alias. Correct?

Answer (score 5):

You can't really do it any simpler than:

```
SELECT item_1 + item_2 + item_3 + item_4
FROM Table1
```

If you have a lot of columns then it will take a while to type in. I guess it took quite a long time to create the table too.

In future design your tables differently so that each stage of the process is a row not a column. In other words, instead of this:

```
id, item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4
```

Your table could look like this:

```
id, item_number, value
```

And then you can query it like this:

```
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM Table1
WHERE id = @id
```

In fact, you probably don't even need the value column. The presence or absence of the row is enough information. So your query becomes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
WHERE id = @id
```

It's perhaps a bit late for you this time, but if you still have a chance to change the design, then it might be worth considering this.

Comment: I can't really do the table of the different design you describe, because each `item` actually is a boolean flag and a value, each one a of different type. So item_1's values might be of a date type, item_2 a string, etc. I still could put all those values in a single string column type, but then I couldn't do native queries on that column, such as date calculations, or SUM().

Comment: Yes, if they are different types, then it would be a bad idea to put them in the same column.