# Get highest percentage value from a column based on value from another column in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query to get the percentages of different values in a specific column:

```
select dma, count(*) / const.cnt *100 as my_percent 
from full_db3 cross join
 (select count(*) as cnt from full_db3) const
group by dma
order by my_percent desc limit 10;
```

Step one: I need to amend this so it gives me the top 10 values in the column `dma` based on the value of another column. For example, if the value in column `gender` is "f", what are the top 10 values in column `dma`. Something like this (which doesn't work, of course).

```
select dma, count(*) where gender = 'female' / const.cnt *100 as my_percent 
from full_db3 cross join
 (select count(*) as cnt from full_db3) const
group by dma
order by my_percent desc limit 10;
```

The above throws an error, but should get the point across.

Step 2 would be looping through all my columns and returning the top 10 values in every column (not just `dma`) give the value of a specific column (e.g., `gender`= 'female'). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Step 1: Do you want to get the percentage of females by dma compared to the whole table? You could write `SUM(IF(gender = 'female',1,0)) / const.cnt *100` or just add add normal `WHERE gender = 'female'` clause at the end (returns same results). Step 2: you will have to explicitly write `IF` clauses for every column.

Comment: @SimoKivistö I figured out where to put the `WHERE` clause. That was a big help.  For step 2, I have 400+ columns, is there any shortcut you can think of?

Comment: Not really. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/22369336/1288184 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2179207/1288184 as the problem is somewhat similar. You could use procedures or scripting for example...