# i want to calculate all numbers in one row from table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to calculate all numbers in one row from table and get the resulting in blade, how can ? i'm using Laravel 5.3?
this my try:

```
{{ $posts = App\Post::where(['counts' => allOf()])->count() }}
```

and this:

```
{{ $posts = App\Post::orderBy('counts', '=', '*')->count() }}
```

but this not working

Comment: count returns a number of rows! What do you need?

Comment: `first()` instead of `count()` maybe? And then do whatever calculations you need? Only thing I can assume from what is given.

Comment: i have a row in table, this row contains a matrix of numbers, i want to calculate this numbers and get the resulting in blade, the row is " counts " in " posts " table @RutvijKothari

Comment: @Das look at to my comment in top

Comment: @MohämmädHämdy how come you have matrix in the row?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to query, at least to me. Are you trying to get the count of ALL your rows of your `Post` table, or are you trying to count ALL the rows of the `Post` table that have the count attribute not null or bigger than 0?

Comment: Do you want to have a sum of all `counts`? Is the `counts` column an integer like 12345?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan yeeeees

Comment: Are you looking for something like this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179207/sum-values-of-a-single-row)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the SUM of the `count`?

If you are using the query builder directly you could use `sum('count')`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#aggregates

Since you appear to be using eloquent you should use `App\Post::all()->sum('count')`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sum

This will gather all the posts into a collection and then sum the count field.

Edit...

Might also try `App\Post::sum('count')`

Comment: If App\Post::sum('count') works, that is the most performant option. This will run a sum() query at the database level rather than all()->sum() which would have to query all rows and then sum the count in php.