# Yii2 querybuilder sum with condition

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

This is my query.

```
$query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['day', 'modeler', 'sum(ifnull(differ, 0)) + sum(ifnull(reworkdiffer, 0)) as total'])
    ->from('loghour3d')
    ->groupBy(['day', 'modeler'])
    ->orderBy(['day'=>SORT_DESC]);
```

This is my table structure.

```
day          modeler    differ    handover     reworkdiffer 
2018-1-05     star        5                         
2018-1-06     star                 star1            3 
2018-1-06     star1       3
```

So i want to sum differ field grouping by day and modeler. My code get me this result:

```
day          modeler    total  
2018-1-05     star        5                         
2018-1-06     star        8        
2018-1-06     star1       3
```

Above, In the date `2018-1-06`, modeler `star` didn't work, instead handover to `star1`, but total is sum to `star` instead of `star1`. Below is the result i want

```
    day          modeler    total  
    2018-1-05     star        5                         
    2018-1-06     star        0        
    2018-1-06     star1       6
```

Is there anyway for me to archive this with querybuilder in yii2? Please advice

Thank you.

Comment: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179207/sum-values-of-a-single-row)

Comment: I can help you but how do you get 6 for star1 ?

Comment: @kiamoz in the date "2018-1-06" `star` handover to `star1` and `star1` works 3 hours, in the same day `star1` works 3 more hours, so total in the date "2018-1-06" of `star` is 0 and `star1` is 6.

Comment: I undrestod let me know you have 2 tables ?

Comment: no, i have one, I've mentioned my table structure above :)